# How would I get SQL Server stored procedure parameter types to their equivalent C# types?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm running an unknown SQL Server stored procedures at runtime for which I can query the SQL output parameter types (varchar, int, etc). Using ADO or Dapper, how do I get the equivalent data types in C#? Currently I get the values as dynamic parameters in Dapper, but I'd like to be able to map them to their specific C# types.

My use case is basically running a stored procedure and and creating a class to hold the output data in their respective C# data types, which will only be known at runtime. I have already found a query that allows me to see their SQL Server data types, and I've heard about ORMs but I'm not sure how or if they can be used for my case.

Comment: `SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters` will build a command object and populate its params collection

Comment: Dapper is an ORM, so you are already using one for this.

Comment: If you only know the type at runtime how do you actually expect to map it to any meaningful object?  You're already using dynamic and, in this instance, that's probably for the best.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a mapping of Sql server data types to .Net

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx